# How to import exsisting project into my eclipse platform without creating new project?

Tags: android, import

I want to import a new android project in somewhere directory.so i just click import and add new project into eclipse platform.
When i run the android  program.it shows a popup dialgog like "The selection can not be launched.there are no recent launches" 
How to import without creating a new project in eclipse platform?

Comment: I click import --->Exsisting project into workspace-->then i click to open my exsisting project into workspace.click Finish...

Then i run the application ..click run confiquration--Set target--Device
run the program.
Still i got the same problem like "The selection can not be launched"

Answer (score 0):

There's no target AVD being set for it. You got to set it's Run Configurations again.

Comment: how to set the target in run configurations